# Observing changes from database to update a list

Tags: android, rx-java

I have this `FriendRepository`:

```
public class FriendRepository {

    //return all friends from database
    public Observable<Friend> getAll() {
        return Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<Friend>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Friend> call() {
                //Query from database and return all friends
            }
        });
    }

    public Observable<Friend> add(Friend friend) {
        //Store a new Friend to database
    }

}
```

In my `ListActivity`, I do something like this:

```
friendRepository.getAll().subscribe(addFriendToList());
```

But, from an Android `Service` maybe a new `Friend` is added, using `FriendRepository.add()` method. I want the `ListActivity` to be aware of this change, so I need to publish it some way. I know `PublishSubject` exists, but I don't know how to use it in this case.

In `FriendRepository.add()` method, I would do something like:

```
    public Observable<Friend> add(Friend friend) {
        return storeFriend().doOnCompleted(new Action0() {
            @Override
            public void call() {
                publisSubject.onNext(friend);           
            }
        });
    }
```

But I don't know what to return in `FriendRepository.getAll()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store that publish subject as a field member and merge it with your the stream for querying like this:

```
public class FriendRepository {

    PublishSubject<Friend> mFriendsSubject = PublishSubject.create();

    //return all friends from database
    public Observable<Friend> getAll() {
        return Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<Friend>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Friend> call() {
                //Query from database and return all friends
            }
        })
        .mergeWith(mPublishSubject);
    }

    public Observable<Friend> add(Friend friend) {
        return storeFriend().doOnCompleted(new Action0() {
            @Override
            public void call() {
                mFriendsSubject.onNext(friend);           
            }
        });
    }

}
```

But notifying in this way violates ***single source of truth***  principle, as you only notify of changes that happen through your repository .. To solve this, I recommend using a database wrapper that handles notification streams for you ( Requery, Realm, SQLBrite etc.. )

Comment: I came across similar approach but it does not expose Subject directly: https://proandroiddev.com/state-propagation-in-android-with-rxjava-subjects-81db49a0dd8e

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

```
public Observable<Friend> getAll() {
    return Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<Friend>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Friend> call() {
            //Query from database and return all friends
        }
    })
    .concatWith(publishSubject.asObservable());
}
```

That way you would get the current state at the time you are subscribing from the `defer` and all future updates through the `Subject`.